# Overwriten casts method, cannot save to database

Tags: php, laravel

I have below model:

`Document.php`

```php
/**
 * Get all of the documents field content.
 *
 * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
 */
public function fields()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Field::class, 'fieldable')
    ->using('App\FieldablePivot')
    ->withPivot(['content', 'type'])
    ->withTimestamps();
}

public function cropped()
{
     return $this->hasMany(CroppedDocumentField::class);
}
```

So in my `fieldables` table, I have a `content` and `type` column. The content can be either an array or a string. This is determinted by the `type` column.

In order to make sure that Laravel casts the correct type when getting the data, I use below code on the `FieldablePivot` model:

```php
public function hasCast($key, $types = null)
{
    if ($key === 'content') {
        return true;
    }
    return parent::hasCast($key, $types);
}

protected function getCastType($key)
{
    if ($key == 'content' && !empty($this->type)) {
        return $this->type;
    }
    return parent::getCastType($key);
}
```

Now when I do:

```php
foreach($document->fields as $field){
       dd($field->pivot->content);
}
```

It returns either an `array` or `string`.

However, when I want to save data to the database, like:

```
$document->cropped()->create([
   'field_id' => 8,
   'content' => "A string",
   'type' => 'string'
]);
```

I get below error:

> **A four digit year could not be found Data missing**

Comment: Does your table have timestamps? If it does check you are setting the created_at, updated_at, etc... fields when inserting.

Comment: It does, but if I remove the override I they are updated automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `hasCasts()` override is not taking into account the `$types` passed in. This causes Laravel to believe that your `content` attribute can be cast to a date (`isDateCastable()` will always return true for `content`), which it attempts to do and fails.

To avoid this, you could just override the `getCasts()` method instead of the `hasCast()` and `getCastType()` methods.

```
public function getCasts()
{
    $casts = parent::getCasts();

    // Add your dynamic cast type to the returned $casts array.
    if (!empty($this->type)) {
        $casts['content'] = $this->type;
    }

    return $casts;
}
```

Now all the other functions will behave as if your `content` attribute were added to the model's `casts` array.

You could also attempt to use model [mutators and accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators), however you would end up having to write the casting functionality yourself, and I don't know if mutators and accessors are taken into account on pivot tables.